# Single statement HOLDLOCK

Tags: locking, sap-ase

I have some legacy code in Sybase ase and there is a statement which contains HOLDLOCK. Due to these hold locks sometimes deadlocks occur. So I want to get rid of hold locks. At the same time, I don't get what the purpose of hold lock in the statement and I guess whether I can just remove hold lock and all would be ok.

Statement is

```
Insert into #temptable
Select
T2.field1,
T1.field1,
T1.field2
From T1 HOLDLOCK
join T2 on T1.field3 = T2.field3
Where some_conditions
Union
Select
T2.field1,
T1.field1,
T1.field2
From T1 HOLDLOCK
join T2 on T1.field3 = T2.field3
Where some_other_conditions
```

When this code run there could run concurrently some other code which updates and inserts T1.

When I've read about hold lock in the documentation it says that isolation level 3 or HOLDLOCK prevents phantom rows or phantom updates. It is when there is one multi-statement transaction which needs to hold locks on data pages so there will be no changes for data pages between two statements.

But here there is one transaction and I don't get what HOLDLOCK is trying to overcome.

Maybe UNION here is a chance to read two versions of the same row from one table?

Comment: if you want remove holdlock for any reasons,the query will run under default isolation level,further the second hold lock is not necessary

Comment: If you are using Sybase then why the `sql-server` tag?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because HOLDLOCK works there the same way. As I know

Comment: My bet is that someone tried to fix performance issues with this hint without too much effort. Of course can't say for sure without knowing more about the system. Best idea would be to just drop it on test environment and see if anything wrong will happen. A bit safer approach might be to wrap it in snapshot isolation level.